# How to stop a user from leaving a textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

My problem is that in VBA I'm not able to stop a user from leaving a textbox after entering a incorrect value. I have tried the .SetFocus however this still allows leave after entering a incorrect value.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

This is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub txtTimeOfDelivery_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Select Case comboDriverID.Value
    Case "1"
If txtTimeOfDelivery < "17:00:00" Or txtTimeOfDelivery > "22:00:00" Then
MsgBox "Warning, the selected delivery time is not within Johns working hours"
txtTimeOfDelivery.SetFocus
Else
Exit Sub
End If
    Case "2"
     If txtTimeOfDelivery < "17:00:00" Or txtTimeOfDelivery > "22:00:00" Then
MsgBox "Warning, the selected delivery time is not within Harrys working hours"
txtTimeOfDelivery.SetFocus
Else
Exit Sub
End If
Case "3"
     If txtTimeOfDelivery < "17:00:00" Or txtTimeOfDelivery > "22:00:00" Then
MsgBox "Warning, the selected delivery time is not within Shaws working hours"
txtTimeOfDelivery.SetFocus
Else
Exit Sub
End If
Case "4"
     If txtTimeOfDelivery < "17:00:00" Or txtTimeOfDelivery > "22:00:00" Then
MsgBox "Warning, the selected delivery time is not within Patricks working hours"
txtTimeOfDelivery.SetFocus
Else
Exit Sub
End If
Case "5"
     If txtTimeOfDelivery < "17:00:00" Or txtTimeOfDelivery > "22:00:00" Then
MsgBox "Warning, the selected delivery time is not within Pauls working hours"
txtTimeOfDelivery.SetFocus
Else
Exit Sub
End If
Case Else
     If txtTimeOfDelivery < "17:00:00" Or txtTimeOfDelivery > "22:00:00" Then
MsgBox "Please carefully check the drivers working hours"
txtTimeOfDelivery.SetFocus
Else
Exit Sub
End If
    End Select
```

I may want to add that this code all works correctly, the only problem is, it lets you leave the text box after you enter a incorrect value

Comment: Can you give examples of what the test box should contain and what it shouldn't?  You can set the format on the control so it will check what the user entered based on data type.  Or, if it is a list of things you want the user to enter then use a combo box.

Comment: It's basically working off checking a combobox has a certain name in it. So if it has Harry in it and the time you enter into the textbox isn't within Harrys working times then it will give you an error. I want to make it so that it doesn't allow you to leave until you enter a correct time however whatever code I try allows you to leave the textbox.

Comment: The code is in the Exit event of the textbox I might want to add.

Comment: Can you show us what you have already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the text box's *Before Update* event to check whether the value is valid. When invalid, `Cancel` the event and the cursor will remain in the text box.

```vb
Private Sub txtTimeOfDelivery_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    ' do your value checking and ...
    ' Cancel when invalid
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the line `Cancel = True` to the event code - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845199.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On the LostFocus event, you could re-set the focus to the textbox if the value is incorrect?